# Csutom annotation to validate Dto contains two list using java validation and spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class Wrapper that contains two arraylist and another properties :

```
public class Wrapper<T, E> {

    private List<T> toInsert = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<T> toUpdate = new ArrayList<>();
    private Set<E> toDelete = new HashSet<>();
    // getter setter ....
}
```

I have a Class Dto :

```
public class UserDto {
    private long id;
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    @NotBlank
    private String registrationNumber;
    @NotBlank
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank
    private String lastName;
    @NotBlank
    private String email;
    @NotBlank
}
```

I create a validator :

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {CustomerLocationValidator.class})
@Documented
public @interface ValidCustomerLocation {
    String message() default "Invalid List  userDto";
    
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

The implementation of validator annotation :

```
public class CustomerLocationValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidCustomerLocation, Wrapper<UserDto, String>> {
    @Autowired
    Validator validator;
    
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Wrapper<UserDto, String> value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        boolean isValid = true;
    
        final Set<ConstraintViolation<UserDto>> constraintViolations = new HashSet();
    
        value.getToInsert().forEach(userDto -> constraintViolations.addAll( validator.validate(userDto)) );
    
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(constraintViolations)) {

            constraintValidatorContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
    
            for (ConstraintViolation<UserDto> violation : constraintViolations) {
    
                constraintValidatorContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(violation.getMessageTemplate()).addConstraintViolation();
            }
            isValid = false;
    
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

The method in controller :

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Void> save(
    @RequestBody  @ValidCustomerLocation Wrapper<UserDto, String> itemsUsers) {}
```

In this controlller I try to send invalid data but the annotation ValidCustomerLocation didn't catch the error , I try to use @Valid  but i have the same problem

Comment: You have to use `@Valid`, not `@validator`

Comment: I mean @Valid  sorry , I updated my question .

Comment: You should add the `@ValidCustomerLocation` annotation at Wrapper class level instead in the controller. You should add `@Valid` though. [Here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/bean-validation/class-level-constraints.html) is a tutorial on how to achieve class level validation